# [Android-Java]Learning android, layout work only once

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am learning how to make an android app, as my first project I'm trying to build a stupid game haha.

when I get to my second activity, The game runs as it has to (picture down)
http://i.imgur.com/BBllAJU.png?1

Than nothing changes, the score, the numbers, but all the toasts still coming.

```
package com.example.moshik.whatisbigger;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.DynamicLayout;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class NormalModeActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

int Score = 0;
boolean AnswerBig = false;
boolean AnswerEqual = false;
boolean AnswerSmall = false;
int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_mode1);
    Random rnd = new Random();


    while (counter < 5) {


        int Number1 = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
        TextView X = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.XNumber);
        String Xstring = String.valueOf(Number1);
        X.setText(Xstring);

        int Number2 = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
        TextView Y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YNumber);
        String Ystring = String.valueOf(Number2);
        Y.setText(Ystring);

        if (Number1 > Number2) {
            AnswerBig = true;
        }
        if (Number1 == Number2) {
            AnswerEqual = true;
        }
        if (Number1 < Number2) {
            AnswerSmall = true;
        }

        findViewById(R.id.Bigger).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerBig) {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(BIG)You are RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    AnswerBig = false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(BIG)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.Equal).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerEqual) {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Equal)You were RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    AnswerEqual = false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Equal)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.Smaller).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerSmall)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Small)You were RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    AnswerSmall = false;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Small)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreDisplay);
        String ScoreShow;
        ScoreShow = String.valueOf(Score);
        score.setText("Your Score Is: " + ScoreShow);
        counter++;

        if (counter > 5)
        {
            score.setText("ItsOver!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.moshik.whatisbigger.NormalModeActivity1">

<include layout="@layout/content_normal_mode1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/ScoreDisplay"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/XNumber"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ScoreDisplay"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ScoreDisplay"
    android:textSize="20sp">


</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/YNumber"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/XNumber"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ScoreDisplay"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ScoreDisplay"
    android:textSize="20sp">

</TextView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Bigger"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:hint="@string/BIG"
    android:layout_below="@+id/XNumber"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</Button>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Equal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Bigger"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="@string/EQUAL">

</Button>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Smaller"
    android:hint="@string/SMALL"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Equal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

</Button>
```

Here is the layout and the activity itself.
Can you find what the problem here or what I miss?, thank you very much :)

Comment: Where are you starting 2nd activity in the code? Why are you extending AppCompatActivity instead of Activity?

Comment: What? Can you explan me what thats means? :3

Comment: @WeareBorg there is nothing wrong with extending `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never updating your score `TextView`. Change it to a class field first so it is easier to access in your callbacks.

```
private TextView score;
```

and then in your `onCreate` method:

```
score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreDisplay);
```

Then update the text in each callback click listener after incrementing Score:

```
Score++;
score.setText("Your Score Is: " + Score);
```

Also, I would update your variable names to be more different as using `Score` for an int and `score` for a `TextView` is confusing.

**Update Showing class field:**

```
public class NormalModeActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    int Score = 0;
    boolean AnswerBig = false;
    boolean AnswerEqual = false;
    boolean AnswerSmall = false;
    int counter = 0;
    TextView X;
    TextView Y;
    TextView score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_mode1);

        // set class fields
        X = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.XNumber);
        Y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YNumber);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreDisplay);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int Number1 = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
        String Xstring = String.valueOf(Number1);
        X.setText(Xstring);

        int Number2 = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
        String Ystring = String.valueOf(Number2);
        Y.setText(Ystring);

        if (Number1 > Number2) {
            AnswerBig = true;
        }
        if (Number1 == Number2) {
            AnswerEqual = true;
        }
        if (Number1 < Number2) {
            AnswerSmall = true;
        }

        findViewById(R.id.Bigger).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerBig) {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(BIG)You are RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    score.setText("Your Score Is: " + Score);
                    AnswerBig = false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(BIG)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                incrementAndCheckCounter();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.Equal).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerEqual) {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Equal)You were RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    score.setText("Your Score Is: " + Score);
                    AnswerEqual = false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Equal)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                incrementAndCheckCounter();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.Smaller).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AnswerSmall)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Small)You were RIGHT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Score++;
                    score.setText("Your Score Is: " + Score);
                    AnswerSmall = false;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NormalModeActivity1.this, "(Small)You were WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                incrementAndCheckCounter();
            }
        });

        String ScoreShow;
        ScoreShow = String.valueOf(Score);
        score.setText("Your Score Is: " + ScoreShow);
    }

    private void incrementAndCheckCounter() {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 5)
        {
            score.setText("ItsOver!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explan me what do you mean in "Change it to a class field"?

Comment: Sure. it means move it outside the onCreate() method to the same area where you have your other fields Score, AnswerBig, AnswerEqual, etc... That way you can access it in all methods of the Class. I updated the answer showing this.

Comment: I did so, and now the score and the numbers are not shown. also the buttons are not working aswell. don't I have to start the code through the onCreate?

Comment: Yes you must keep your onCreate method. You will find it still needs a bit more fixing but just change the location of `TextView score;` and `score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreDisplay);` like in the updated answer and the `score` should update when the button is pressed if you add `score.setText("Your Score Is: " + Score);` after each time you do `Score++`.

Comment: Note the ... in the `onCreate` method means put the rest of your code there to avoid making the post longer.

Comment: Dude the whole code, I mean the 'game' where the random value and so, it has to be inside the onCreate?

Comment: No it does not have to be inside onCreate. Really you just need to get a reference to the views you will be using in onCreate by doing `findViewById(...)` and initialize their default values and events such as click listeners. I can tell you another problem with your code is the `while` loop you have in `onCreate`.

Comment: Sry for being stupid and so haha, but I really don't understand :\ where do I have to put the whole, 'game'? cause If I put the code outside of oncreate it won't run.
Look at the comment below to see my new code after changing what You said.

Comment: I added full code to try and help you out. Take a look.

Comment: Does this make sense now?

Comment: Thank you very very much! , just one small thing, how to loop is working here, and why the while isn't right?

Comment: Because it looks like you want to give the user 5 guesses to win the game. The way you had it before the user would not be able to guess at all and by the time your activity is shown they would have already lost the game. You only want to increment your counter after they have made a guess by clicking one of the buttons.

Comment: The meaning is the 'while' working before the activity start, while the creation?

Comment: Pretty much yes. You need an event driven counter based on when the user clicks a button and not a procedural counter like your while loop.

Comment: I have done, Fix the two numbers and the score working as well, I think I got it now. Thank you very much mate! :D